# Error connecting to agent: no such file or directory - adding key to ssh agent

Tags: ssh, clone, ssh-keys, bitbucket.org

I am trying to add key that I have generated to the ssh agent. Below are my steps

```
C:\repo>ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (C:\Users\mante1/.ssh/id_rsa):C:\repo\key
```

After the key is generated, I am starting the ssh agent and adding it

```
C:\repo>start-ssh-agent
Found ssh-agent at 13460
Found ssh-agent socket at /tmp/ssh-vKzdrs37QYVK/agent.821

C:\repo>ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Error connecting to agent: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Could you show the output of `where ssh-add` and `where start-ssh-agent`? What is the reason for specifying ~/.ssh/id_rsa as the key path even though this is a Windows system?

Comment: id-rsa is same of my key which is stored within the "Repo" folder. 

```
C:\repo>start-ssh-agent
Found ssh-agent at 11556
Found ssh-agent socket at /tmp/ssh-XZKCZ7JYan9x/agent.1387

@user1686 C:\repo>ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Error connecting to agent: No such file or directory
```